# What is the easiest way to draw a rounded line next to a paragraph?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a vertical line next to my text. I can just use 'border-left' to draw a vertical line on the left, but I didn't find out yet how to round it's corners. The following image shows how it should be about:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an absolutely positioned pseudo-element to achieve the same purpose. In the example below, I am using `::before` that is absolutely positioned and set to the full height of the parent (using the `top: 0; bottom: 0;` trick). You can then simply set a width and use a `border-radius` that is half the width to achieve the rounded corners.

```css
p {
  position: relative; /* Required so that pseudo-element is positioned correctly */
  padding-left: 30px; /* Dummy value to make space for pseudo-element */
}

p::before {
  /* Create pseudo-element and give it content */
  content: '';
  display: block;
  
  /* Position it in its parent so that it is:
   * - to the left
   * - occupies full height
   */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  /* Give it a fixed width and rounded corners */
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  
  /* Appearance */
  background-color: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sollicitudin metus tincidunt felis maximus, maximus sollicitudin mi ultrices. Curabitur libero arcu, bibendum ac suscipit ut, elementum scelerisque lacus. Praesent ultricies commodo porttitor. Fusce eget velit nisi. Praesent vulputate venenatis dui, efficitur sollicitudin nisi pulvinar a.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```css
.txt {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
}

.txt:before {
    content: '';
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: skyblue;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

p {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="txt">
 <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sollicitudin metus tincidunt felis maximus, maximus sollicitudin mi ultrices. Curabitur libero arcu, bibendum ac suscipit ut, elementum scelerisque lacus. Praesent ultricies commodo porttitor. Fusce eget velit nisi. Praesent vulputate venenatis dui, efficitur sollicitudin nisi pulvinar.
 </p>
</div>
```